# Why use if in to check string value is no working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry for very basic question. I am not familiar with Python.

I check my mac terminal `python --version` is 3.7.6

and I use the code

```
if '/watch?v=YtJ9dkFgjeQ' in '=':
  print('Include =')
else:
  print('fail')
  pass
```

I want to check include `=` or not, but no idea why it prints fail.

Comment: if  '=' in  '/watch?v=YtJ9dkFgjeQ':

Comment: `if A in B` does not check if B is in A

Comment: I do not understand the down votes here. Related to StackOverflow rules it is a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply switch the sides

```
if '=' in '/watch?v=YtJ9dkFgjeQ':
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
print('Include =' if '/watch?v=YtJ9dkFgjeQ'.count("=") > 0 else 'fail')
```

or

```
print('Include =' if '/watch?v=YtJ9dkFgjeQ'.find("=") > 0 else 'fail')
```

This will check if `"="` in string `'/watch?v=YtJ9dkFgjeQ'` and print the relevant output.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if '=' in '/watch?v=YtJ9dkFgjeQ':
  print('Include =')
else:
  print('fail')
  pass
```

You can also use

```
print('Include =') if '=' in '/watch?v=YtJ9dkFgjeQ' else print('fail')
```